# Probability of a choice overlapping N times in a row or more when choosing K items from a selection of size M

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are total of 13 players in a game, and 4 of them are assigned "evil" randomly. Some players have noted, that some players have been evil multiple times in a row (specifically, a player was evil 5 times in a row over 5 games). I am wondering about this specific probability, that is, what is the chance that we would observe this behavior, for any player (not just this particular player).

In addition to that, I want to know the general probability for this problem: M players, K assigned "evil", and over N games any 1 or more player being assigned "evil" N times in a row.

Bonus question, a curiosity: What about if there weren't 5 games, but L games in total, and a streak of N or more?

---

The best thing I can solve for now is simply the probability that a specific player will be "evil" 5 times in a row:

(4/13)^5 = ~0.2757%

I tried some things with C(12, 3)^5/C(13, 4)^5, but that simply yields the result for a single specific person, and doesn't take into consideration the fact that multiple people could overlap too

---

I attempted to code up a simulation which would simply check this ([link to jsfiddle, freezes browser for a bit](https://jsfiddle.net/6mgv3bzc/17/)). My result seems to be around 3.55342%, which seems oddly close to (4/13)^5 * 13= 3.58530%, which seems surprising.

I also tried enumerating each possibility, however, it seems like this method wouldn't be fruitful, as the number of total possibilities is around C(13,4)^5 = 186865965446875 (Or C(M, K)^L), which is something my computer couldn't be able to handle. Possibly there are ways of optimizing this though...

Comment: Hi! How could you be assigned "evil" N times in a row or more, when there are only N games being played?

Comment: As a bonus, why don't you let us know what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution applies to the original game: 13 players in all, 4 selected as "evil" each round, 5 rounds, and we want to know the probability that there is at least one player who is selected as evil in all 5 rounds.

There are $\binom{13}{4}$ possible ways to choose the $4$ evil  players in each round and a sequence of $5$ independent rounds, so there are $\binom{13}{4}^5$ possible outcomes, all of which we assume are equally likely.

If there is a set of $j$ players who are selected as evil in all $5$ rounds, then the number of possible outcomes is $\binom{13-j}{4-j}^5$, for $1 \le j \le 4$.  The set of $j$ players can be selected in $\binom{13}{j}$ ways.

So by Inclusion / Exclusion, the probability that at least one player is selected as evil in all the rounds is
$$\sum_{j=1}^4 (-1)^{j-1} \binom{13}{j} \binom{13-j}{4-j}^5 / \binom{13}{4}^5 = 0.03564316 $$

Comment: I still don't quite understand the last part. More elaboration would be appreciated (a more intuitive explanation for each step?)
"If there is a set of j players who are selected as evil in all 5 rounds": I am trying to figure out the situation with j = 1, which I understand to be: if there is 1 player who is evil in 5 rounds: C(13-1, 4-1)^5 possible outcomes. And that player can be any of the 13, so 13*C(12,3)^5 possible outcomes, thus probability that 1 player is evil in 5 rounds is: C(12, 3)^5*C(13, 1)/C(13,4)^5. However, this seems incorrect, as it's value is greater than your answer.

Comment: @Zobody The reason that the figure for the probability that one player is evil in 5 rounds is higher than the final answer is that the one-player value overcounts.  If, for example, player A is counted as evil, then he ends up being counted twice in cases where both A and B are evil.  That's the reason for inclusion / exclusion, to correct for overcounting.